# Quote a string using {fmt}

Tags: c++, fmt

Is there any way to print a string as quoted using [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt)?

Here is an example code showing what I want to achieve:

```cpp
fmt::print("Hello {}!", "Terens");
```

I want the code to print `Hello "Terens"!` instead of just `Hello Terens!`.

EDIT: I want to use the API for printing different data not known beforehand (I am writing this for a library, so I specifically want a quoted output when the data is a `std::string` or `std::string_view`.

Comment: `"Hello \"{}\"!"` or `R"(Hello "{}"!)"`?

Comment: I want to use it with different types, but want to surround the output with quotes if it is a string.

Comment: You could change the "Terens" into "\"Terens\"" - and any other string you want output in quotes

Comment: @ericpat I don't want people to quote their string by themselves. I think I will use a `is_string` trait and a ternary on the format string.

Comment: If you know that the input is going to be a string - you could make a preprocessor macro to add quotes around their input like #define QUOTE(x) "\"" x "\"" and pass QUOTE(szInput) as the parameter to fmt::print

Comment: You might create a wrapper class/function `template <typename T>const T& Quote(const T& t) { return t; } std::string Quote(const std::string& s) { return "\"" + s + "\""; }` and then`template <typename T> void hello(const T& arg) { fmt::print("hello {}!", Quote(arg)); }.`

Comment: Or wrapping your own type, you might [customize](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#formatting-user-defined-types).

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm aware of `fmt::formatter`, but I'm not sure I can customize it for `std::string` (AFAIK it is already specialised). Writing a `Quote` method looks good, but I think I will write a `is_string_like` trait and use an `if constexpr` for separating the cases.

Comment: `Quote` method here **create** new string (with its overhead :-/), returning a `QuoteWrapper<T>` would allow to have customization point with your type (and indeed you cannot (and should not even if it was possible) add (external) customization for foreign type, at least one should be your).

Comment: How do you want your api to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to use the API for printing different data not known beforehand (I am writing this for a library, so I specifically want a quoted output when the data is a std::string or std::string_view.

The following code:

```
#include <fmt/core.h>

template<typename T>
const T& myprint_get(const T& t) {
    return t;
}
std::string myprint_get(const std::string& t) {
    return "\"" + t + "\"";
}

template<typename ...T>
void myprint(const char *fmt, T... t) {
    fmt::print(fmt, myprint_get(t)...);
}

int main() {
    myprint("{} {}", std::string("string"), 5);
}
```

[outputs](https://godbolt.org/z/YKj5vW):

```
"string" 5
```

It should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Excellent solution. I think I will use `fmt::format` instead of `"\"" + str "\""` since I want it to work with `std::string_view` as well.

Comment: `fmt::format` is a waste of cpu to just suffix/prefix with `"`, just `"\"" + std::string(str) + "\""` copy the string.

Comment: @KamilCuk Are we certain that creating and appending to a temporary `string` is better than `fmt::format()`ting to one? For all I know, `fmt` does some magic to `reserve` and `append` more efficiently...

Answer (score 5):

You can either wrap `"{}"` in quotes in the format string or use the `?` specifier. For example (https://godbolt.org/z/nxajzs5so):

```
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main(){
  fmt::print("Hello {:?}!", "Terens");
}
```

Output:

```
Hello "Terens"!
```

Comment: I totally forgot about `std::quoted`. Looks perfect for this case, thank you!

Comment: Sadly, it looks like the version of `<format>` adopted into C++20 doesn't contain `std::quoted` support; and (probably for that reason) version 9 of {fmt} removed support for `std::quoted` too. So now `fmt::format("Hello \"{}\"!", "Terens")` is the best you can do, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Quuxplusone, thanks for pointing this out. {fmt} now has built-in escaping support with ?. I updated the answer.

Comment: @vitaut, is this feature documented? If so, where can I find documentation for it?

Comment: It still needs to be added to the {fmt} docs but check out https://eel.is/c++draft/format#string.std-19